# Why can't my test script connect to a SQL Server database?

Tags: sql-server, iis

I have the following PHP script to test if my user can connect to my
SQL Server database:

```
<?php
$serverName = "ABC-XXXXXXX";
$uid = "my_user";
$pwd = "my_password";
$databaseName = "my_database";

$connectionInfo = array("UID"=>$uid,
                        "PWD"=>$pwd,
                        "Database"=>$databaseName);

$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

var_dump($conn);
```

The connection fails, and I'm not sure why, but I'm guessing it's either because I am using the wrong `$serverName` or the user doesn't have the right permissions.

To get the `$serverName`, in SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS), I have followed these steps:

1. Open the object explorer.
2. Right-click on the database and click on Properties.
3. Click "View connection properties" in the left column.
4. In the Server Environment section, I use the value for the Computer Name row.

To grant the user access to the database, I have tried both SSMS and also tried a query, but I'm not sure if either had the desired effect.

The query I ran was...

```
USE [my_database];

GRANT SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE 
ON SCHEMA :: [dbo] TO my_user;
```

The query completes successfully, but I'm not sure if this gives the user access to the database. If I look at the user's permission in the SSMS object explorer (my_database > Security > Users > (right-click) my_user > Properties), it looks like the query had the desired effect.  There is a line for the dbo schema, and if I click on that line I see that the SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT and DELETE boxes are checked below.  However, I am not sure if I need to grant other permissions besides these to connect to the database from my script.

The web server is IIS and the OS is Windows 10.

UPDATE: When I print the `sqlsrv_errors()`, I see

> Login failed for user 'my_user'

UPDATE 2: When I change the "Server authentication" setting to "SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode" and run my test script, there is an additional error message:

> Cannot open database "my_database" requested by the login. The login failed.

UPDATE 3:  After going to Security > Logins > my_user (right-click) > Properties > Securables and checking the box for "Connect any database," the error message has changed to:

> The SELECT permission was denied on the object 'block_content', database 'my_database', schema 'dbo'.

UPDATE 4:  My test script was able to connect to the database after I assigned my database user to the 'sysadmin' role at Security > Logins > my_user (right-click) > Properties > Server Roles.  Though it's possible the other actions I took (following the suggestions in the comments) also contributed.

Comment: _"The connection fails, and I'm not sure why,"_ - what's the error message?

Comment: I updated the question to include the error.  The error is "Login failed for user 'my_user'".

Comment: So use the correct password then...

Comment: As far as I know, I am.  I have set the password in the object explorer at Security > Logins > my_user > right-click Properties.  Then I enter the desired password in the fields for Password and Confirm Password.

Comment: Check the SQL Server Audit logs (assuming you have Failure Auditing enabled), as it gives you the exact reason for the login failure: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/auditing/view-a-sql-server-audit-log?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: You may need to uncheck the `User must change password at next login` check box on the `General` tab of login properties. (`Security`->`Logins`) You may also need to clear the `Login is locked out` on the `Status` tab of login properties. Your user likely already has it, but it's worth checking if it has the `CONNECT` permission too.

Comment: could you try to set the iis application pool identity permission or use iis application pool identity to the custom account which has enough permission to access the database

Comment: @Dai have Failure Auditing enabled, but when I navigate to the Audits folder in the object explorer, the folder can't be expanded.  It is empty.

Comment: @PatrickHurst Those settings are all unchecked and greyed out.  I don't see any CONNECT permission listed in the Securables page for the user.  There doesn't appear to be any such permission.

Comment: @Dai  The Audits folder is empty, but I updated my answer with a new error message sqlsrv_errors() gives me after I changed a setting.

Comment: @JalpaPanchal I don't have a database user who can access the database.  I am only able to open the database in SSMS by using Windows Authentication.

Comment: @arnoldbird you should see `Connect SQL` under the `Securables` tab of the login, under the Server type. You should also be able to find `Connect` under the `Securables` tab of the user under the database type.

Comment: Do you have mixed mode authentication enabled on the instance?

Comment: @PatrickHurst Getting closer! After checking the box for Connect SQL under Securables, I now see an error message that references a specific table:  "The SELECT permission was denied on the object 'block_content', database 'my_database', schema 'dbo'."  How can I grant the user permission on all tables?  Is that the missing piece? I would think the SQL query in my question above would do it, but I must be missing something still.

Comment: @PatrickHurst  Actually there are two Connect SQL boxes, and one has a grantor of "SA" and one has no grantor.  That one with the grantor was already checked, I believe.  I checked the other one as well, but it doesn't stay checked.  But I also checked the box for Connect Any Database -- maybe that's what changed the error message I'm seeing.

Comment: @arnoldbird you have some options on how to do that. You can make the user a member of the db_datareader role in the database. You can explicitly grant select to the table, or you can grant the login a server level role.
`ALTER ROLE <rolename> ADD MEMBER <username>`  `GRANT SELECT ON <schemaname>.<tablename> TO <username>`

Comment: Sounds like the user didn't have `CONNECT` on the database in question. If you did not specify a default database for your user it would have defaulted to `master`. You should always specify the database you intend to connect to in the connection string, to guarantee you end up in it. You should probably check it has connect on the appropriate database.

Comment: @PatrickHurst  I just now changed the user's default database to the one I am connecting to in the script but this did not change the error I am seeing.  I do indeed specify the database in the script in my question above.  "You should probably check it has connect on the appropriate database."  I'd love to know how!  I have done many web searches and tried many different things in SSMS but the simple test script in my question above still cannot connect to the database.

Comment: @PatrickHurst  "you have some options on how to do that."  I am just trying to get to first base any way I can.  My goal is to get the test script to connect to my database by any means possible, as this is for local development purposes only.  "You can make the user a member of the db_datareader..."  I don't see that role.  But I would be happy to do anything that connects this test script to the database. I am not picky about how.  Anything!  Thank you.

Comment: @arnoldbird <Database>->Security->Users->Properties. Securables tab. Select your database (search button, all objects of type... check databases) scroll down to the `CONNECT` permission.

Comment: It's always a good idea to pursue least permissions from the get go. If all you need is select that grant that. If a role is a better fit then use that.
You can read about the roles here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/database-level-roles?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: @PatrickHurst  I got the script to connect just now by going to Security > Logins > my_user (right-click) > Properties > Server Roles and checking all the boxes.  "It's always a good idea to pursue least permissions from the get go"  Probably so, but I wanted to see some proof that I could get the script to connect somehow on this machine, to make sure there was no intractable problem.  This is my first time using MS SQL and it is a very different beast than other databases I've used.  Thanks for your help!  I will tighten things down a bit now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To summarize the conversation in the comments, and provide an answer to the question for posterity:

Every login has a default database, if you do not specify one `master` is assumed. You can change the default database for a login using TSQL `ALTER LOGIN <LoginName> WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE = <DatabaseName>` or using the SSMS gui: `Security->Logins->Properties` At the bottom of the general tab is Default database.

You should specify a database in your connection string. This can very depending on what you're using to connect, but typically it's `Database=<DatabaseName>;`.

You'll need to grant the user permissions to the objects you want it to be able to use. You're best off if you can apply **least permission** from the get go.

A user needs permission to connect to the database, you can grant this using TSQL: `GRANT CONNECT ON Database::<DatabaseName> TO <UserName>;` or through the GUI: `Databases-><Database>->Security->Users-><User>->Properties` Search, All Objects of the types..., Databases, Select the database and scroll down to Connect.

You can grant permissions to individual objects using TSQL: `GRANT SELECT ON <SchemaName>.<ObjectName> TO <UserName>;`.
A database role might be more appropriate: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/database-level-roles?view=sql-server-ver16. You can add a user to a role using TSQL: `ALTER ROLE <RoleName> ADD MEMBER <UserName>;`.
You can also grant server level roles which have a wider scope, if that's appropriate.